# gm.py x64.release Errorr---env: python: No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, build, v8, gm, gn

macos **monterey 12.3.1**

python -V: **python3**

which python3: `/usr/local/bin/python3`

alias python="/usr/bin/python3"

path: `/Users/Bill/Public/browser/depot_tools /usr/local/bin /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin`

proxy: proxychains4 + tor socks5 127.0.0.1 9150

cloned dedepot_tools in `git clone https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools.git`

run `gclient` working good

run: `fetch v8`

run: `gclient sync` working good

run: `tools/dev/gm.py x64.release`

show:
`env: python: No such file or directory`

how to fix it?

should install python-is-python3?

`brew info python-is-python3`

`Error: No available formula with the name "python-is-python3". Did you mean python-tk@3.9?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a short-term workaround, you have two options:

(1) Create a symlink `python` in your `$PATH` that references `python3`. This can be done in one of several ways:

- Some Linux distros have a `python-is-python3` package for that
- Some distros have other "official" ways to do it
- Or you can just `sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python` (or whatever the correct paths are on your system).

(2) You can call `gm.py` with an explicit Python binary:
`python3 tools/dev/gm.py`

Medium-term, `gm.py` should be updated to require `python3` directly. The fact that it doesn't do so yet is an artifact of the Python2-to-Python3 migration.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I solved the problem perfectly using `python3 tools/dev/gm.py`. I'm a bit guilty of knowing `node file.js`. and not being able to work around `python file.py`. shame on me!